# How can I add users to my Fiori launchpad?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I have a fiori launchpad with some apps. And I want to achieve that different users see different apps on my launchpad. So, I created some catalogs and roles. But I don't know how I can add users. 
I have a second account and this account should see my launchpad with apps that belong to its role.
How can I do this?

Or alternatively I don't need other accounts? I'm a bit confused. Could someone explain me how the user assignment works?

Comment: What Fiori Launchpad (FLP) do you have? Is it an FLP on the SAP Cloud Platform  (SAPCP) via Portal Service or is an FLP served from NW ABAP? In case it's the first one (from SAPCP), are you using the Provisioning Service?

Answer (score 1):

Please see [this link about configuring roles](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_nw74/7.4.16/en-US/44/5570c460b24244bbacd962fe731326/frameset.htm): Users need authorization roles to run the SAP Fiori launchpad (as an end user) and the SAP Fiori launchpad designer (as an administrator). 
When users have these roles, they can access the catalogs and groups assigned to the roles by a role administrator. 
As a role administrator, you assign the necessary authorization roles and adjust them according to your needs.

Please [read here about assigning users to roles](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_nw74/7.4.16/en-US/44/5570c460b24244bbacd962fe731326/frameset.htm). A role administrator makes tile catalogs and tile groups available to users by assigning them to an authorization role.
As a role administrator you assign users of the SAP Fiori launchpad (end-users) and launchpad designer (administrators) 
to authorization roles in User Maintenance (transaction SU01) or in Role Maintenance (transaction PFCG).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will read this.
Question: Both links from you show the same page. Did you maybe mean this link: https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_nw74/7.4.16/en-US/44/5570c460b24244bbacd962fe731326/frameset.htm?

Comment: The first link is supposed to go to this section: Configuring Roles with Launchpad Start Authorizations. Sorry!

Comment: Ah, my link has the wrong destination, too. Ups. 
Are these steps really necessary to authorize users? Do I have to use NetWeaver? I just want that a user logs in and sees the apps that I assigned to him (by email address or something).

Comment: Please see [Assigning business roles to a user](https://websmp106.sap-ag.de/~sapidp/012002523100012419282015E/frameset.htm?88e84ba4d9b84c3c8fe43defe3d0f401.html) and [Creating basic settings for using SAP Fiori launchpad](https://websmp104.sap-ag.de/~sapidp/012002523100012419282015E/frameset.htm?557553cabc684579b0260827903dbaf2.html) They  provide general information about the SAP Fiori artefacts in SAP S/4HANA and list basic settings in the back-end system
for using the SAP Fiori launchpad with the delivered roles and business catalogs.

Comment: If you use the SAP Fiori Launchpad as user interface, a prerequisite is that you have roles assigned to your Fiori user in the NetWeaver Gateway system.
SAP delivers a bundle of business roles as templates for customers.

Answer (score 1):

When you say 'categories', I assume they are 'Catalogs'.

You need to assign "apps to Catalogs", "Catalogs to a Role" and at last "Role to the users". This is how users get **authorization** to the apps.

But users will not yet see those apps in their Launchpad. But it will be accessible in the "[App Finder](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/app-finder/)" for them to launch. If you want these apps to appear in the Launchpad as well, then you need to assign
"apps to Groups", "Groups to a Role (this can be the above Role as well)", and then this "role to the user".

To assign Role to the user, open the role in transaction code PFCG. Under 'Users' tab, you can list/add the users who are going to have it.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer, @krisho! 
Could you explain me how I can assign "role to user"?

Comment: Yeah, updated the answer. Let me know if you require more info.

Comment: Thanks for your help! 
How can I execute a transaction code? (Google didn't help me...)
Do I have to install anything to do this?

Comment: Maybe this can help https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sap/sap_navigating.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you are still stuck with assigning roles to user:

tcode "SU01" > select the user and open in display mode>

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLOkx.jpg)

here click on "Roles" then click on display/change icon and add your role into the blank white spaces for role. Here we assigned "VA01", a customized role. :)